# How to send custom property name in delete option using feathersjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, feathersjs, http-delete

I want to delete the document in a collection., In feathers accept only id not any specific property name for deletion.

**My url is:** http://localhost:8080/workers?userId=3

```
function(hook,next){
      if(hook.params.query.userId){
          hook.app.service('users')
            .remove({ query: {userId: hook.params.query.userId}})
            .then(result=>{
              console.log(result,'result');
              });
      } else {
        next();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `null` as the id to `remove` to remove entries according to a query. It is documented [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#removeid-params) and [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#adapterremoveid-params---promise). So

```
hook.app.service('users').remove(null, { query: {userId: hook.params.query.userId}})
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: To remove a list of items, you can use the following.

```js
hook.app.service('users').remove(null, { query: { userId: $in: [ hook.params.query.userId ] } } )
```

Comment: @Daff, how do you write this as a rest call? Ignoring the <id> doesn't work. I tried `DELETE /subscribedclubs?clubId=1`

Comment: Ok, I needed to add `multi: true` to the service options

Answer (score 1):

Send the extra parameters as query parameters in the URL e.g

```
/delete/<id>/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

then access these parameters in your service as

```
const {param1, param2} = params.query;
```

Comment: What if you don't have a specific id, but want to delete all with param1 and param2  ? What do you use instead of <id>  ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the id of the document and then pass that into the remove method afaik. This is much safer than attempting to delete on a property value.

Comment: I don't want use id, i want to use userId or any other property to remove document. is it possible? @Glitcher

Comment: I don't think it is. Best bet it to just do a "find" with the userId, and then pass the id from that into remove. it is an extra step, but not particularly taxing